# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

So comes the end of the latest of the even numbered years to date. Or maybe for you it has already come. All that matters is that it means that it's time for another round of Community Promotion Ads to reset! And a lot of "that"s in a row.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- your ventrilo or Mumble server
- the site's twitter account
- resources or databases for gaming information
- indie games that are awesome, but people might not know about
- game servers or gaming nights
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/10168).

Answer (score 26):

[image: Child's Play - Give games to kids in hospital]

Comment: An updated ad with the new logo.

Comment: ...this is way bigger than 250x220px...

Comment: +1 This ad is a good idea.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin It's fine. They work.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Pay what you want, support charity, get incredible games: The Humble Bundle]

Comment: I have a new version of this ad for this year. [Yes, this size will work fine](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/community-promotion-ads-2014?lq=1#comment3648_1884).

Answer (score 13):

[image: Raspberry Pi StackExchange - What will you do with yours?]

Comment: I'm reposting this: by clickthroughs it was the most popular ad last year.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Join the Arqade Community on Steam!]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Come and join us on Community Building Stack Exchange!]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Join our community in Manyland: The open universe we create and live together.]

Comment: considering down voting just becaus of the time wasted on this fabulous site

Comment: Is this a binding of issac or Fez clone or something?  With GladOS?

Comment: It's a MMO exploration and creation game. This is a screenshot of some creations in the game.

Answer (score 10):

[image: GameChops | Professional Video Game Remixes]

Comment: Text still looks a bit shit at the smaller size, but it's more descriptive than the other one.

Answer (score 9):

[image: The Indie Royale: Grab awesome games and music!]

Answer (score 8):

[image: OpenTTD - Transport Tycoon for the 21st Century]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Join Mythology Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Movies & TV Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Be prepared with Hardware Recs SE!]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Free Culture Now! - Visit Open Source SE]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Visit Health Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Skydrift]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Y'all know the drill by now.

Comment: I'll repeat my comment from last year: I don't think this is a good ad to display, our twitter feed is not the best representation of our community.

Comment: The twitter feed is how I read about half of the questions I nowadays do, so I would like to see it promoted.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Transcendence: Journey to the Core (PC, rogue-like/RPG game)]

Comment: This is an ad to the Steam Greenlight page of a game I absolutely adore (yes, it's already playable and has been for years!).

Comment: Do you think it'd be worth adding some text?

Comment: @Robotnik Definitely. I'll try doing so soon. I have a midterm tomorrow, but once I am done, I'll see if I can't add some. I wonder if no text has some curiosity value :p

Comment: while the game is great (how long has it been around anyway?), the add definitely needs some text. Why not add the name of the game?

Comment: @Monika Done. The game has been out since the early 2000s, but continues to be developed and expanded.

Answer (score -4):

[image: Lifehacks Stack Exchange]

Comment: I really don't know if I should upvote or downvote...

Comment: @MBraedley So far the consensus seems to be to downvote. Oh well, I tried.

Comment: What's with the size of this and other images? Do sizes that are multiples of, not just exactly, 200×250px work on Arqade?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie They are twice the display dimensions: 440x500px. This means they will look nicer on Apple's Retina® screens, and other high-dpi environments.

Comment: @fredley Do they work though? The OP still says that CA images must be 200×250.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie [Yes](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/community-promotion-ads-2014?lq=1#comment3648_1884)

Comment: How am I going to clean the lifehack cartridge if I can't read the instructional cartridge cleaning material on the lifehack cartridge?